# Differences in website display between Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am running the same live server from both Safari and Chrome to test my website but it seems that the `right:;` property is handled differently in Safari and Chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="navbar" style="z-index:3; position: fixed; float: right;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 16%, rgba(255,255,255,0.98) 52%, rgba(255,255,255,0.92) 73%, rgba(255,255,255,0.57) 90%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 16%,rgba(255,255,255,0.98) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0.92) 73%,rgba(255,255,255,0.57) 90%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 16%,rgba(255,255,255,0.98) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0.92) 73%,rgba(255,255,255,0.57) 90%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */" >
        <div class='container'>
            <b href="****" rel='home button'>
                <img src="img/logo.png" width='135' height='42' style="padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 2vw; padding-left: 2vw; max-height: 42px;">
            </b>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="story.html"> STORY</a></li>
                <li><a href=""> VISION</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ACTION CENTRE</a></li>
                <li><a href="">GET IN TOUCH</a></li>
                <li class="translate"><a href=""class = "translate"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#266BCC" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-globe"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="2" y1="12" x2="22" y2="12"></line><path d="M12 2a15.3 15.3 0 0 1 4 10 15.3 15.3 0 0 1-4 10 15.3 15.3 0 0 1-4-10 15.3 15.3 0 0 1 4-10z"></path></svg></a></li>
                <li class="donate"><a href="" class="donate">DONATE</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <style>
       * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    }

    body,html {
        margin: 0;
        font: bold 14px/1.4 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    ul { 
        margin: 0px; 
        padding: 0; 
        list-style: none; 
        display: table;
        width: 800px;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100px;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
        padding-left: 10vw;
        position: absolute;
        /** here   **/
        right:230px;
    }
    li { 
        display: table-cell; 
        position: relative; 
        padding: 0px 0;
        height: 0px;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    a {
        color: #266BCC;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        letter-spacing: 0.15em;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        position: relative;
        min-width: 150px;
        width: auto;
        /** here **/
        right: 0px;
    
        
    }
    a:after {    
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        bottom: 0;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        left: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        background: #266BCC;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
        -o-transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
        transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
        width: 0;
    }
    a:hover:after { 
        width: 100%; 
        left: 0; 
    }

    .container {

    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    float: left;
    z-index: 100;
    }


    .donate {
    color: #DB504A;
    }

    .donate::after {
    background-color: #DB504A;
    }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem area is noted. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAlkm.png) is a screen shot of `right:0px;` and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNSTc.png) is a screen shot of when `right:230px;`. The donate button is off the screen in Safari even though they are running from the same live server. The problem even persists with the code snippet when opened on Chrome and Safari. How would I fix this so that the donate button is visible on both browsers aka the format is the same?

Comment: I would strongly suggest removing all inline `style=""` attributes in favor of a single `style` element in the `head` of the document. Also, combining `display: ` (anything other than `block`) with `position: ` (anything other than the default, `static`) is a recipe for disaster. Throwing in `float` just compounds the problem. I would rethink the approach and use `display: flex` or `display: grid` consistently.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very sketchy fix for the problem but I used JavaScript to detect the type of browser being used and adjust accordingly:

```
window.onload = function() { browserChecker()};

var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 

var ul = document.getElementById('ul');

function browserChecker() {
    if (ua.indexOf('safari') != -1) { 
        if (ua.indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
            ul.classList.add('ulChrome');
        } else {
            ul.classList.add('ulSafari');
        }
    }
}
```